# WSO2 Api Manager 2.0.0 Log Analyzer error

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

When I try to use Log Analyzer functionality in API Manager 2.0.0 Admin Portal, I get this error

`ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call property authenticate in object [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.an
alytics.jsservice.Utils]. It is not a function, it is "object". (/portal/controllers/apis/analytics.jag#90) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call property authenticate in object [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.analytics.jsservice.Utils]. It is not a function,
 it is "object". (/portal/controllers/apis/analytics.jag#90)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
        at ...`

How can i fix this?

It looks like a problem with jaggery app, because I am getting this other error when trying to load Api-Avaliability page.

`ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: < (/admin/site/blocks/api-availability/ajax/api-availability.jag#71) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: < (/admin/site/blocks/api-availability/ajax/api-availability.jag#71)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
...`

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: $ java -version
 java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)